# Raspberry pi ca-certificates issue wget

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to make sudo rpi-update command (firmware updater).
I tried many ways , time is set correctly and have install ca-certificates, but I still have following error
!!! Failed to download update for rpi-update
!!! Make sure you have ca-certificates installed and that the time is set corrctly

Answer (score 3):

I tried every proposed solution. None of them worked except for purge.

```
sudo apt-get purge ca-certificates
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

I ended up running

```
sudo autoremove
```

which removed a bunch of old packages that weren't previously marked for removal.

```
sudo rpi-update
```

Update then worked. I'm not sure if this is a correct or elegant solution but it was the only action that worked. This post may be old but hope that it will help someone since I have had this issue recently and for a long time.

Comment: thanks sudo apt-get purge ca-certificates
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates, that also worked for me